# How to get a list of particular data from quickdb?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to make list command to list the stored data for this code , I tried a lot but it doesn't work for me

```js
run: async (client, message, args) => {
message.delete({ timeout: 1000 })
if (!client.config.bowner.includes(message.author.id)) return;
if (!args[0]) {
  return message.reply(
    new discord.MessageEmbed({
      color: client.embed.cf,
      description: "Target user not mentioned!",
    })
  );
}
const target =
  message.mentions.members.first() ||
  message.guild.members.guild.cache.get[0];

if (!args[1]) return message.reply("Add or Remove")

if (args[1] === "add") {
  db.push("noprefix" + target.id)
  return message.reply("Done").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }))
} else if (args[1] === 'remove') {
  db.delete("noprefix" + target.id)
  return message.reply("Done").then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 3000 }))
}
```

Comment: So is there any specific error that you are getting with this issue? Or attempt at making a simple reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm using this code

`let noprefix = db.get('noprefix')
      if(!owners) return message.channel.send('There are no users to show!')
      else  message.channel.send('The owners are ' + noprefix.join(' and '))`

but it always show's their is no user to show, if i remove that part than their is a error at join

Answer (score 0):

In your database there's no exact `noprefix` db. There's always something next to `noprefix` as you said, `+ target id`. So you can collect noprefix things in your one data as `noprefix` and make it an array, then push every noprefix things into it. Then you can use it.